Is the AOSP documentation source markup publicly available?
Occasionally, I want to reference topics like https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview. However, because their content changes, referring back to them without saving them in their entirety (via archivers like https://web.archive.org/, or extensions like SingleFile and its myriad competitors) can be difficult.
Were I to be able to access its source markup stored on a version control system like git (I can't imagine they use SVN) I would be able to refernece versioned documentation, like I can at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a48127f0276e1fb4e309776b4216160fd5b67e56/core/java/android/os/Users.md#user. Consequently, is the documentation source rendered at the aforementioned URIs publicly available, like the referenced android.googlesource.com markup is?
I ask because Microsoft provides this at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs, so I would be surprised if Google didn't. However, I've been unable to locate it.

I've never seen the source code of Android Developer documentation. AFAIK, it's not part of the Android Open Source Project.

@AndrewT., a shame. They're missing out on contributions.

Back in the early days the developer site was part of the SDK 1 and 2, then a program for low bandwidth areas to get a full dev kit, aka GDG Dev Kit Pilot (2014) was released (once). The site source.android.com stopped being mirrored in their git repo in 2021.

@MorrisonChang, that seems like an answer. Many thanks.

Per Morrison Chang's comment, it appears not, anymore:

Back in the early days the developer site was part of the SDK 1 and 2, then a program for low bandwidth areas to get a full dev kit, aka GDG Dev Kit Pilot (2014) was released (once). The site source.android.com stopped being mirrored in their git repo in 2021.

Despite initial semi-apathetic enthusiasm to remediate this, Google has confirmed that the choice to not publicly mirror it is deliberate, due to low utilisation:

Hi, regarding providing the source code for source.android.com in AOSP, following up on comment #2, it was decided to stop mirroring the source code for documentation in AOSP due to low usage and low amount of external contributions and high bandwidth required for syncing with the Git mirror. Closing this out as intended behavior.


For filing bugs against documentation see: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/contribute/report-bugs#documentation

@MorrisonChang, I've filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364052457#comment1 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364089356#comment1.
